# Is there Java Control Panel in java -16?

Tags: java, java-15, java-16, java-console

Hi am new to java and I was using java 15. Then a newer version of java came and it was 16.
I downloaded it and installed it in my computer. Then I found that you can update java using java control panel. But I can't found it. Can anyone help me? Is there Java Control Panel in jdk-16 ?

Comment: You need to provide details of what system you're running on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Oracle Java 16 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/migrate/removed-tools-and-components.html), the Control Panel was removed in Java 11.

It *may or may not be* present in other Java distros.  *If it is still present*, you should be able to find it as `ControlPanel` or `jcontrol` in the Java installation's `bin` or `jre/bin` directory.  (Or `javacpl.exe` + `javacpl.cpl` on Windows.)

---

However as @Holger notes, it is doubtful that you would be able to use the Control Panel to update Java (for Java 11 and later) anyway.  The standard Control Panel relies on Oracle-managed update servers, and it is unlikely that those servers would (or could) serve upgrades for a 3rd-party Java distro.

You are better off updating Java some other way; i.e. by downloading and running the Windows installer.

(Note that Oracle *want* vendors of Java-based applications to take responsibility for distributing their Java platform to end users; e.g. by shipping custom JREs generated using `jlink`.  If you are still advising your users / customers to upgrade Java via the Control Panel, you are "doing it wrong" ... since Java 9.)

Comment: For Windows installations, the executable is `javacpl.exe` but the file relevant to the integration into the system’s control panel is `javacpl.cpl`. But whether using the control panel to update Java works, is a different question, as that requires the collaboration of some update server maintained by Oracle.

Comment: @Holger I am getting an error` 'javacpl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: @Java - Holger is referring to the name that the command would have ... *if it was still available* on your Windows Java install.  As noted, it is NOT available in an Oracle Java installation for Java 11 or later.  The official release notes clearly say that it has been removed.